# How to configure mulitiple properties for a vertex in tinkerpop gremlin server with neo4j db

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I am using tinkerpop's gremlin server with neo4j db.
How to set the vertex property cardinality to set or list?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Multiple properties on a vertex is not supported 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty$Exceptions.multiPropertiesNotSupported(VertexProperty.java:99) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.trait.NoMultiNoMetaNeo4jTrait.setVertexProperty(NoMultiNoMetaNeo4jTrait.java:101) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jVertex.property(Neo4jVertex.java:85) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.AddPropertyStep.sideEffect(AddPropertyStep.java:121) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.sideEffect.SideEffectStep.processNextStart(SideEffectStep.java:39) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.hasNext(AbstractStep.java:143) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.hasNext(DefaultTraversal.java:192) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.AbstractOpProcessor.handleIterator(AbstractOpProcessor.java:89) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.AbstractEvalOpProcessor.lambda$evalOpInternal$5(AbstractEvalOpProcessor.java:252) 
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:273) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found neo4j graph config over here, [neo4j graph multi/meta properties](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/docs/src/reference/implementations-neo4j.asciidoc#vertex-properties)
I have tried setting these following properties in neo4j.properties. The last three ones.

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph 
gremlin.neo4j.directory=/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db 
gremlin.neo4j.conf.node_auto_indexing=true 
gremlin.neo4j.conf.relationship_auto_indexing=true 
gremlin.neo4j.conf.allow_store_upgrade=true 
gremlin.neo4j.conf.multiProperties=true 
gremlin.neo4j.conf.metaProperties=true 
gremlin.tinkergraph.defaultVertexPropertyCardinality=list
```

So, this happens when I do a query like this

```
g.V().addV('Stephen').property(set, '1','2')
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things...first, `gremlin.tinkergraph.defaultVertexPropertyCardinality=list` is not a "neo4j" configuration option. Second, I don't think that you are calling `property()` right. It should be more like the example in the link you provided:

```
gremlin> g.addV().property('name','michael').property('name','michael hunger').property('name','mhunger')
==>v[0]
```

Thus in your case you would do:

```
gremlin> g.addV('person').property(set,'name','Stephen').property(set,'name','Stephen').property(set,'name','steve').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().properties('name')
==>vp[name->Stephen]
==>vp[name->steve]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've at it and there has been some development. I installed neo4j again and used this new db file. I put the properties
gremlin.neo4j.multiProperties=true 
gremlin.neo4j.metaProperties=true

and I did g.addV('User').property(set, '1','2').property(set, '1',3')
I got this
gremlin> g.V().valueMap().unfold()
==>1=[3, 2]

Seems like Once the data is inserted without the meta and multi properties, It doesn't allow to add multi properties further even if the properties are set later on.

Now I'm trying to copy the data from that old db to this new one in which multi prop works